# How to properly initialise property of the class considering that it's value will be assigned later dynamically?

Tags: typescript, vue-class-components

Below is the Vue component class with an event listeners that can receive an instance of service worker at some point of time and save it under `registration` property.

The problem I experience is that even doing:

```
if (this.registration && this.registration.waiting) {
  this.registration.waiting.postMessage(SERVICE_WORKER_MESSAGES.skipWaiting)
}
```

TypeScript communicates that `this.registration` is `TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.` which makes sense because of:
`private registration: unknown`

I would really appreciate if somebody could suggest what is a proper way of initialising and access properties that can be defined later?

P.S: The actual type of `registration` is `ServiceWorkerRegistration`

**Class implementation:**

```
export default class Core extends Vue {
  private refreshing = false
  private updateExists = false
  private registration: unknown

  updateApp (): void {
    this.updateExists = false

    // this.registration --> TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
    if (this.registration && this.registration.waiting) {
      //                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  

      // this.registration --> TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
      this.registration.waiting.postMessage(SERVICE_WORKER_MESSAGES.skipWaiting)
      // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    }
  }

  addEventListeners () {
    document.addEventListener(SERVICE_WORKER_EVENTS.updated, ((event: CustomEvent) => {
      this.registration = event.detail /* store the ServiceWorkerRegistration instance for later use. */
      this.updateExists = true
    }) as EventListener,
    { once: true })
  }

  created () {
    this.addEventListeners()

    /*
    Refresh all open app tabs when a new service worker is installed */
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener(`controllerchange`, () => {
      if (!this.refreshing) {
        this.refreshing = true
        window.location.reload()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `registration` is not initialized when the instance is created it can be `undefined`.

You can mark it as [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties):

```
private registration?: ServiceWorkerRegistration
```

Or explicitly specify that it can be `undefined`:

```
private registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration | undefined
```

---

Using non-null assertion operator is actually a **bad idea** because it will allow accessing `this.registration` properties without checking if it is defined/initialized or not.

Comment: Thank you, Aleksey, your suggestion actually makes sense especially in the context of this particular class functionality purpose :-)

Comment: @volna by the way, you instead of `if` you could use optional chaining  operator: `this.registration?.waiting?.postMessage(SERVICE_WORKER_MESSAGES.skipWaiting)`

Comment: Code above runs in 3.5.3 TS version, I've double checked your suggestion about `Using non-null assertion operator is actually a bad idea because it will allow accessing this.registration properties without checking if it is defined/initialized or not.`

Comment: and using Terry suggestion of non-null operator actually still warns that the object can be possible null since there is no actual initializer, if access it without the previous type guard check

Comment: But I still agree to mark the property as optional or explicitly say it can be undefined is a bit more developer-friendly

Comment: @volna try, no warning here (that's the point of non null assertion) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2AnAptA3gWAFDWgB0QEsA3MAF1RQHNCIzFzD4A7AQgC5oBlZRYw4MgDqSANa8ASshp0GZJs2zZcAVzwATcsgCCePAAoAlOmW5oZABa0AdNVr1GLawHcwhecyoBuUwF9svkA

Comment: Oh.. I see, thank you for sharing Aleksey. The way I performed described above test is this way: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2AnAptA3gWAFDWgB0QEsA3MAF1RQHNCIzFzD4A7AQgC5oBlZRYw4MgDqSANa8ASshp0GZJs2zZcAVzwATcsgCCePAAoAlOmW5oZABa0AdNVr1GLawHcwhecyqmAvtl9ZsUEgYBBQAIQBPADV4EGYwExx8IlIKaDtZRzZOHj4BYTFJaXs5BSUktU0KXQNjTCTcSxsMh3knV3dCT2s8eDoAWWQoMCpkHz8gA

Comment: You can see there that even with non-null assertion TS still forbids the usage of the methods of that property.

Comment: @volna yes, that's not related to nun null assertion - you're accessing `postMessage`  of inner property `waiting` of the registration which is defined as nullable `ServiceWorker | null`

Comment: Makes sense, Aleksey :-) thank you once again for all your time and attitude you shared helping me :bowing: